# On Java8 I cannot inherit an overriden inherited annotation

Tags: java, java-8, cdi

I have an annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InheritedQualifier {
     public String value();
}
```

and I have four classes that make use of it.

- Parent which has `@InheritedQualifier("original")`
- Child which extends Parent but makes no modification
- GrandChild which extends Parent and has `@InheritedQualifier("override")`
- GreatGrandChild which extends GrandChild but makes no modification

All four classes also implement @Named with unique Names. Finally I have a fifth class with the following injection:

```
@Inject @InheritedQualifier("original") @Named("parent") Parent parent;
@Inject @InheritedQualifier("original") @Named("child") Child child;
@Inject @InheritedQualifier("override") @Named("grandChild") GrandChild grandChild;
@Inject @InheritedQualifier("override") @Named("greatGrandChild") GreatGrandChild greatGrandChild;
```

Now here's the weird thing. When I run this on Oracle's Java7 it works fine. When I run it on Java8 it fails to inject GreatGrandChild. Here's the error message:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [com.ibm.ws.fat.jcdi.inheritance.GreatGrandChild] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers:[@javax.inject.Named(value=greatGrandChild),@com.ibm.ws.fat.jcdi.inheritance.InheritedQualifier(value=override)]
for injection into Field Injection Point, field name :  greatGrandChild, Bean Owner : [MyBean, Name:myBean, WebBeans Type:MANAGED, API Types:[com.ibm.ws.fat.jcdi.inheritance.MyBean,java.lang.Object], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.inject.Named]]
at org.apache.webbeans.util.InjectionExceptionUtils.throwUnsatisfiedResolutionException(InjectionExceptionUtils.java:77)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.InjectionResolver.checkInjectionPoints(InjectionResolver.java:193)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.validate(BeanManagerImpl.java:1031)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validate(BeansDeployer.java:444)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.validateInjectionPoints(BeansDeployer.java:383)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:184)
at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:155)
at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:97)
at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.WebBeansInitializer.onStartup(WebBeansInitializer.java:70)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2485)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6404)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:449)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:254)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The other three injection's work fine.

I'm running this application on IBM Websphere Liberty Profile.

Does anyone have any idea why this code isn't portable from Java7 to Java8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in the application server; it has now been patched.

Answer (score 0):

This link [Troubleshooting contexts and dependency injection](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_troubleshoot_cdi.html)

suggests you have some kind of class-path problem. You've said that when you run in java 7 the application works fine, but with java 8 it does not. Is the execution environment difference *only* the JVM used? For example, the only change you did to run the program with java 8 was to point the same Liberty Profile to a different JVM?

If that is not the case, there is a big chance that the difference is between two execution environments instead of two different JVMs.

However, you mention in the comments that the only change is the JAVA_HOME environment variable. So, you may have struck just a possible application framework bug, or a bug within java itself.

My suggestions now is:

If it don't work with java 8, avoid using it. Java 8 is kind of new, it's less than one year old. For server usage, it is a baby... BY the way, the latest Websphere specification only supports java 6 or 7... Check it out: [Websphere 8.5.5 requirements - java](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProductByComponent?deliverableId=1337870535828&duComponent=Server_118F7A80A6C511E2A4CA497F0925FE1B#osFamily-4)

There are known incompatibilities between java 7 and java 8, and maybe you have just struck one of them, indirectly: 
[incompatibilities between java 7 and 8- oracle doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999198)

Comment: The only difference is the JVM used. I run the server it works fine, then I shut the server down, change JAVA_HOME, start it up again, and the problem appears.

Comment: There are subtle differences between the different java versions, and maybe you've just struct one of those...